# Performing operation on integer value in dictionary

Tags: python

```py
chessclubset = { "name" : ["joe", "mama", "bob", "billy"],
                  "Age" : ["10", "11", "12", "14"],
                  "Grade" : ["10", "11", "12", "9"]}
print(chessclubset)
value = chessclubset["Age"]
print(value)

value = chessclubset["Age"][0] += 1
print(value)
```

I want to be able to add one to my value of "age" in my dictionary, to make the age value 11 instead of 10. It does not allow me to perform an operation on the value, as it is a string, but I am not sure how to go about converting it into an integer, so that I can still perform this action.

Comment: Drop quotation marks around numbers.

Comment: Is it a must that values are strings? Create your dictionary with integers, or use `int()` to convert

Comment: Your last but one statement `value = chessclubset["Age"][0] += 1` will raise Syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `int()` to convert the string to an integer.

```
value = int(chessclubset["Age"][0]) + 1
chessclubset["Age"][0] = str(value)
print(value)
```

Comment: The first line `value = int(chessclubset["Age"][0]) =+ 1` will raise syntax error.

Comment: I meant to change `+=` to just `+`, but mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chessclubset = { "name" : ["joe", "mama", "bob", "billy"],
              "Age" : ["10", "11", "12", "14"],
              "Grade" : ["10", "11", "12", "9"]}
print(chessclubset)
value = chessclubset["Age"]
print(value)

value = int(chessclubset["Age"][0])
chessclubset["Age"][0] = str(value + 1)
print(chessclubset["Age"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the initial dictionary such that those elements are of type integer. Then switch the addition line so that it's a legal statement, and you can reassign the value in the dictionary.

```
chessclubset = { "name" : ["joe", "mama", "bob", "billy"],
              "Age" : [10, 11, 12, 14],
              "Grade" : [10, 11, 12, 9]}
print(chessclubset)
value = chessclubset["Age"]
print(value)
chessclubset["Age"][0] = chessclubset["Age"][0] + 1
print(value)
```